# Join in bookshelf.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, bookshelf.js

How do i achieve the following relation in bookshelf.js

```
SELECT user_accounts.user_id,  `event_id` 
FROM  `calendar_events` 
JOIN user_accounts ON user_accounts.user_id = calendar_events.`created_by` 
LIMIT 10
```

My Model

```
var CalendarEvent = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'calendar_events',
    hasTimestamps: ['created_on'],
    user: function() {
        return this.hasOne('UserAccount','user_id');
    }
});

var UserAccount = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'user_account'
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to get that exact style query, you could use the knex query builder and try to build a query to match your needs

*have not tested this but should be something like this*

```
CalendarEvent.forge().query(function(qb){
  qb.join('user_accounts', 'user_accounts.user_id', '=', 'calendar_events.created_by');
  //qb.where() //if you wanted
  //qb.andWhere();  //and if you wanted more
  qb.limit(10);

})    
.fetchAll();
```

*(you dont need the .where or .andWhere, just added those for fun)*

It might be possible to do it purely in bookshelf, but i'm not sure of how at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you found the solution since 2016 but here is the answer

```
var CalendarEvent = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'calendar_events',
    hasTimestamps: ['created_on'],
    user: function() {
        return this.belongsTo(UserAccount, 'user_id', 'created_by');
    }
});

var UserAccount = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'user_account'
});
```

Use belongsTo() method because the foreign key is in the CalendarEvent Model and not in the UserAccount model. Append the name of the foreign key to belongsTo() parameters to specify the name of the foreign key.

Then, use the Bookshelf model like this :

```
CalendarEvent
    .forge()
    .fetchPage({ pageSize: 10, withRelated: ['user'] })
    .then(data => {
        // Data retrieval
    })
    .catch(exc => {
        // Error management
    });
```

The fetchPage method uses `page` and `pageSize` to create a pagination. You will retrieve a `data.pagination` object containing rows info (number to rows, page number, page size, page total count) and `data.toJSON()` will retrieve your models.

Comment: This does not do a single join query. It makes two sql queries, one to fetch CalendarEvent and another for UserAccount.

Comment: That's true but that's not the question. OP wanted to know how to achieve his query using Bookshelf, I'm giving the answer. One or multiple queries is not the question.